# Update a model after deleting a row in another model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models `UserProfile` and `ChatUser`.
`ChatUser.models.py`

```
class ChatUser(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`UserProfile.models.py`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image',blank=True,default='prof1.jpeg')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    joined = JSONField(null=True)
```

`ChatRoom.models`

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    eid = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vehicle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    max_limit = models.IntegerField()
```

`joined` in UserProfile is an array consisting room ids of the chatrooms model.  Now when I delete a ChatRoom row, it automatically deletes the Foreign Key referenced ChatUser object since I am using `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. But how to update the `joined` in UserProfile model. I want to remove the id of the deleted ChatRoom from `UserProfile.joined`

Comment: It is here better to use a `ManyToManyField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField A JSON field is better for data with a "dynamic *structure*".

Comment: I am using this way so that it will be easy to check if user has joined or not. In this way: `if request.user.userprofile.joined`. Also to check if a particular room_id, the user has joined in this way: `if id in request.user.userprofile.joined`.  Is there any way to do the same in `ManyToManyField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the `django.db.models.signals` to solve the updating part.

```
@receiver(post_delete,sender=ChatUser)
def update_profile(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    id = instance.chat_id
    joined = instance.user.userprofile.joined
    if id in joined:
        joined.remove(id)
    model = profiles.models.UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=instance.user.id).update(joined=joined)
```

[SDRJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14438609/sdrj) and [Willem Van OnSem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem), thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

@SAI SANTOSH CHIRAG- Please explain this. You have a ChatUser model that adds user_id and chatroom_id. Now, if I need to find out the list of chatrooms a user has joined, I can simply query this model. If I want to find out the total number of users in a specific chatroom then I can still query this table. Why do I need to keep track of joined in UserProfile? And I am basing this on the premise that joined keeps track of chatroom ids that a user has joined.

At any point, if you choose to add a many-to-many field in any of the models then this is my opinion. E.g Let's assume that you add the following in the UserProfile model

```
chatroom = models.ManytoManyField(Chat)
```

Imagine as the number of chatrooms the user joins grows, the list becomes larger and larger and I find it inconvenient because I will have this tiny scroll bar with a large list. It's not wrong but I simply stay away from M2M field for this purpose especially if I expect my list to grow as my application scales.

I prefer the ChatUser approach that you used. Yes, I might have repeating rows of user_ids or repeating chatroom_ids but I don't mind. I can live with it. It's still a bit cleaner to me. And this is simply my opinion. Feel free to disagree.
Lastly, I would rename the ChatUser model to ChatRoomUser...Why? Just by the name of it, I can infer it has something to do with two entities Chatroom and User.